# "non-const lvalue reference to type cannot bind" error with reference (Type &) but not with pointer (Type *)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants, lvalue

I am getting this error "Non-const lvalue to type 'Cell' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Cell *' with this code :

```
class RegionHolder
{    
public:
    RegionHolder(Region& Region1):m_RegionCellNOO(&(Region1.m_NOO))
    ~RegionHolder();

protected:
    Cell & m_RegionCellNOO; // difference is here   
};
```

but not with this one :

```
class RegionHolder
{    
public:
    RegionHolder(Region& Region1):m_RegionCellNOO(&(Region1.m_NOO))
    ~RegionHolder();

protected:
    Cell * m_RegionCellNOO; // difference is here   
};
```

I don't understand the problem and would really like to use references and not pointers.

Thanks

Comment: For one, you're trying to assign an address to a reference in the first block.

Comment: `&(Region1.m_NOO)` is a pointer. Of course you can't bind an `int&` to an `int*`, so why should it be different for a `Cell&` and `Cell*`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to show us the definition, but presumably `Region1.m_NOO` is an object of type `Cell`. Your first example is taking the address of it, and trying to use the resulting pointer to initialise a reference. References aren't initialised from pointers, but from the object itself:

```
RegionHolder(Region& Region1):m_RegionCellNOO(Region1.m_NOO) {}
//                                            ^ no &         ^^ don't forget that
```

There is one caveat with using references rather than pointers: they are not assignable, and so neither is your class. Often that's not a problem; but if you do need your class to be assignable, then you'll need to use a pointer instead.

Answer (score 2):

The unary `&` operator gets a pointer to a variable. So, in C++ (as in C) `a = &b` gets a pointer to `b` and stores this value in `a`, so if `b` is of type `int`, `a` needs to be of type `int*`. Assignment to references, on the other hand, is implicit, so if a is of type `int&` you simply need to write `a=b` to make `a` a reference to `b`. So in your case, you need to rewrite your constructor as

```
RegionHolder(Region& Region1):m_RegionCellNOO(Region1.m_NOO) {}
```

However, I think you're better off using pointers than references here *anyway* and trying to use C++ without getting comfortable with pointers is a very bad idea. So I suggest you take the time to make yourself comfortable with using pointers instead of trying to avoid them.

Comment: Great, I'll try to stick with pointers then. Is there any way I can access Region1.m_NOO if this variable is private within Region class?

Comment: No, that's the point of `private`. If you want to access it you need to either (1) make `RegionHolder::RegionHolder` a friend of `Region` or (2) add an accessor function to `Region`, e.g. `Region* GetNOO() { return &m_Noo; }`